# Sub Menu Close Delay With Multiple Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

I have a multi-level drop-down menu built only with `CSS`. The drop-down waits for a second before closing when mouse is moved away. However, there's multiple drop-downs under the main navigation, so when the mouse moves from one menu to other, the delay is causing the old drop-down menu to stay open behind the newly opened one.

Basically what I need is to delay the drop-down closing when the mouse moves away, but close the drop-down immediately if the mouse goes over another menu and thus preventing multiple drop-down-menu stacking one above another. Solutions with `jQuery` is also appreciated.

My current code is in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zj9nLu38/11/) and in the snippet below:

```css
.main-navigation {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 105%;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0s 0.5s;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
  left: -999em;
  top: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li:hover>ul,
.main-navigation ul ul li.focus>ul {
  left: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a {
  width: 250px;
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover>ul,
.main-navigation ul li.focus>ul {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.main-navigation li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation li a,
.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a,
.navigation li.disabled {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation li {
  display: inline;
}

.navigation li a,
.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a,
.navigation li.disabled {
  background-color: #6FB7E9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}

.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a {
  background-color: #3C8DC5;
}

.navigation ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.sub-menu li {
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu {
  background-color: #419bd0;
  border-top: 3px solid #2d6b90;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <div class="menu-main-nav-container">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Link Parent</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Other</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="/">Link B</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link B</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link B</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link B</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can disable other dropdowns for a while when the current dropdown is hovered over. You can use `mouseenter` event to disable them and `mousleave` event to enable them again.

Comment: It would be better if you could show us the complete code

Comment: @RakibulIslam No problem see here: https://jsfiddle.net/zj9nLu38/11/ If you hover over the first 'link parent' link and then hover over 'other' you'll see other get's overlapped onto the parent link content - how can this be avoided?

Comment: I can't see the problem in the fiddle. Can you? If so, please update the fiddle so we could see the problem.

Comment: @MoshFeu I can see the problem in the fiddle, I've just updated - if you quickly change between the two drop downs you will see them overlap (dark blue bar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: It's a little hack but the logic is to set the transition delay only for 
"not hover" state so it will happen only on mouse out.

```css
.main-navigation:not(:hover) ul ul {
  transition: 0s 0.5s;
}
```

**Working example**

```css
.main-navigation {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.main-navigation:not(:hover) ul ul {
  transition: 0s 0.5s;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 105%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
  left: -999em;
  top: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li:hover>ul,
.main-navigation ul ul li.focus>ul {
  left: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a {
  width: 250px;
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover>ul,
.main-navigation ul li.focus>ul {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.main-navigation li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation li a,
.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a,
.navigation li.disabled {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation li {
  display: inline;
}

.navigation li a,
.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a,
.navigation li.disabled {
  background-color: #6FB7E9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}

.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a {
  background-color: #3C8DC5;
}

.navigation ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.sub-menu li {
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu {
  background-color: #419bd0;
  border-top: 3px solid #2d6b90;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <div class="menu-main-nav-container">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Link Parent</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Other</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="/">Link B</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link B</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link B</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link B</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `transition` from `.main-navigation ul ul`, rather add it in `.main-navigation ul li>ul` like below:

```
.main-navigation ul li>ul {
  transition: visibility 0.5s;
}
```

Working code here:

```css
.main-navigation {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 105%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
  left: -999em;
  top: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li:hover>ul,
.main-navigation ul ul li:focus>ul {
  left: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a {
  width: 250px;
}

.main-navigation ul li>ul {
  transition: visibility 0.5s;
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover>ul,
.main-navigation ul li:focus>ul {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.main-navigation li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu li {
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu {
  background-color: #419bd0;
  border-top: 3px solid #2d6b90;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <div>
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Link Parent</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link A</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Other</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="/">Link B</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link B</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link B</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">Link B</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zj9nLu38/40/

Comment: Looks like you misunderstood the question, OP wants the drop-down to hide with delay after hover out, but no delay if hovered over any other menu.

Comment: @MunimMunna Ow, really, I misunderstood then, thanks for sharing your thoughts :)

Comment: @MonkeyFace Well, I didn't understand then. I've edited my answer. Maybe this is something you wanted, though I'm not sure. Please give some feedback.